# why is afterSetExtremes function being called twice highcharts using react

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I want to implement lazy loading functionality as show here.

[jsfiddle.net/uf34oecg/](https://Example)

If you check its console, it prints `loadInitialData` once only at the time of loading the chart for the first time.
Then it never prints it or once you select `1m` (after first load), it calls `afterSetExtremes` function and prints `afterSetExtremes`.

---

I found the same example converted to reactjs code

https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-wvrd6?file=/demo.jsx:673-688

In this example when you load for the first time, it calls `afterSetExtremes` twice which is wrong. It should not call `afterSetExtremes` at initial loading.

I don't understand why is that happening? I'm unable to figure it out after spending couple of hours.

Because of it, it behaves badly in real project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there are different orders of action.

With React:

1. Chart is created without data
2. Data is received and the chart is updated

Without React:

1. Data is received
2. Chart is created

---

As a solution, you can call `loadInitialData` in `useEffect` hook and render `HighchartsReact` component after the data has been received.

```
const ChartComponent = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadInitialData();
  }, []);

  function loadInitialData() {
    fetch(dataURL)
      .then((res) => res.ok && res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        ...
        setOptions({
          ...chartOptions,
          series: [
            {
              data
            }
          ],
          ...
        });
      });
  }

  function afterSetExtremes(e) {
    ...
  }

  return (
    options && (
      <HighchartsReact
        constructorType="stockChart"
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={options}
      />
    )
  );
};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-3tcdw7?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: This is really great. It solves the problem. However, for some reason, in my case, it keeps calling `afterSetExtremes` again and again when you click on `1y` option. any idea?

Comment: in your example also, it always makes two calls when you click on any zoom option.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Shah, That's because `adaptToUpdatedData` option is lost during the options merge. Please check the updated example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-fork-btsrpu?file=/demo.jsx